# Have an active accesstoken, but still getting the error - An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

An active accesstoken is available, but I am still getting an error while using the latest Facebook SDK like

> code = 2500;
>   
> message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";

Below is the code I am using.

```
if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen) 
{
    appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"status_update"]];
    NSLog(@"Access Token Available == %@", appDelegate.session.accessTokenData.accessToken);

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/feed"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Testing from iOS", @"description",@"Testing FB Status Update", @"message", nil] HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){
        if(error)
        {
           NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
        }
        else
           NSLog(@"Posted !");

    }];
}
```

What is the actual problem...?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parameter list add **access_token** parameter too.

You can also verify the access token here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: thanks for that.... It worked by adding access_token to the parameter list... thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: Am glad that it helped.

Comment: same problem for me in which parameter u are telling to add accesstoken

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you don't have the permission granted for the query. Have the user allowed the app to get the info you are trying? Try out the tools on the developers.facebook.com. Very useful to debug the API.